# Process names in MS Message Analyzer

Tags: traffic, packet-capture, network-traffic, packet-sniffer, message-queuing

I am trying to set up the Message Analyzer viewer exactly like it is explained [in this reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt764113.aspx), but instead of steady process names I got some weird numbers, both in ProcessName and ProcessID columns.

[image]

I use standard Wireless scenario

[image]

and following ETW providers

[image]

The capture got by `netsh trace start scenario=wlan capture=yes` had the same view

[image]

How to get process names here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to require Windows_Kernel_Trace messages to provide process names. I had the same problem that you did where I applied a session filter before the session start including an IP Address filter. I changed my filter to:

```
!(*Port in [3389, 1494, 1503]) and (IPv4.Address == 10.0.0.123 or Windows_Kernel_Trace)
```

Process names now appear for most messages.

Answer (score 0):

I post it as an intermediate answer until I get detailed comment from Microsoft about this issue (which might happen never).

By trial and error I figured out the above issue happens **only** when I specify session filter **prior** to live trace start. I use very big IP-based filtering that looks like this:

```
*Port!=3389 and
((IPv4.Address in 2.16.106.48/28 ) or
(IPv4.Address in 2.16.106.64/27 ) or
(IPv4.Address in 2.16.106.96/28 ) or
(IPv4.Address in 2.16.106.112/29 ) or
(IPv4.Address in 2.16.106.120/31 ) or
(IPv4.Address in 2.16.106.122/32 ) or
(IPv4.Address ==  2.19.177.129 ) or
...
many lines
```

But if I [apply session filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649784.aspx) **after** session start, then all goes fine and process names are showed as expected. I cannot properly explain this phenomenon as filtering has nothing to do with process names (which are provided by kernel), and obviously it has nothing to do and **should** have nothing to do with the moment you apply filters: either after or before session start.

Just one more bummer from Microsoft...